# How to De-index Non-existing Pages URL from Google

Tags: google, google-index

How I can remove the non-existing pages URL from Google.

There are a lot of pages which doesn't exist on our website. How to remove their URL from Google.

Comment: How long has it been since the pages have been removed?   If it is more than two weeks something else is probably wrong?  Google automatically de-indexes pages that return 404 Not found status.     How many URLS are you talking about anyway?  Google has a tool to remove them one at a time more quickly, but if you have a lot that won't work.

Comment: Unfortunatelly before 5 months my site was hacked with "japanese keyword hack",after 5 months i still see 32k of unexisted pages in search console,so,answer is,we cant remove them,on that question google-s John Mueller said - Who knows.
All these stories with redirections in .htaccess and blocking in robots.txt are nice,but these stories stops indexing of your real pages.

Answer (score 4):

1. You need to go to [Google Search Console](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/).
2. On the sidebar, click "Google Index" and then select "Delete URLs.
3. Press "Create a new deletion request.
4. Enter the URL in the appropriate form.
5. Select "Remove page from search results and cache" and click "Submit Request".

#### `robots.txt` file

This method can be used to remove an unwanted page or an entire section from the results. To do this, you must have access to the root folder of the domain. This file should contain the following lines:

- `User-agent`: here you will need to enter the name of the robot to which the ban will be applied.
- `Disallow`: Here you will need to enter the address itself.
  In this case you will also have to wait for reindexing, until it will not be thrown out of the index. You can, of course, send the page forcibly on the relinking, but that's another story.

Comment: Part in sidebar about you talking doesnt exist.

Answer (score 3):

If the pages are minimal, you can submit in the Google Search Console - Removal Tool found here: https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/removals

If the pages are greater, you can submit a new sitemap to let Google update your indexed URLs and give time for them to de-index the irrelevant URLs as long as they are not found or have the 'noindex' tag.

In both of the cases, if you're not aware why lot of pages are appearing on your website that you have not created, please check the following:

- Dealing with Hacked Sites/Content
- Your external/internal backlinks that point to the non-existent URL

Answer (score 2):

1. Get into knowledge repeated patterns containing in non-existing urls
2. Fire `410 Gone` with PHP, like:

`<?php
     if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == '(pattern1|pattern2)') {
       header ("HTTP/1.1 410 Gone");
     }
?>`

On this way Google learns quickly, that these urls don't exist and de-indexes them quickly.

Another way is to fire `noindex` with X-Robots-Tag, like

```
<?php
    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == '(pattern1|pattern2)') {
      header("X-Robots-Tag: noindex, nofollow", true);
    }
?>
```

but the de-indexing happens (much) slower.